# Custom wordpress Theme and Plugin repository

Tags: plugins, customization, themes, server, repository

I am looking for a guide/guidance to create a proper custom wordpress repository for themes and plugins hosted on a website hosting account. I do not want to host it on github.com or anywhere else. I searched in google but without any success so far. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the plugins and themes for sale or download or just have them accessible to download for updates?

Comment: I would like to have them available for direct install and/or download.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it all depends on what you are actually looking for, but you can use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) as your installer and use [packagist](https://github.com/composer/packagist) which is the code of [packagist.org](http://packagist.org) to install on your server. It is also used by [wpackagist.org](http://wpackagist.org/).

An article on how to set this up on an ubuntu server can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-custom-composer-repository-on-ubuntu).

If you are looking for a marketplace for plugins and themes then that's something different altogether.